# List of tutorials and sources to start developing on IOTA

Tags: development

I am looking for documentation about IOTA and development tools. Also if you know examples of real-life applications (industrial and commercial) it would be appreciated.

I am interested mainly in python and JavaScript development tools.

Comment: What category or even language you are looking for? I know there are already some resources you can start with. But I think it can be more directly and easier if you specific the range.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering I updated the question to indicate the languages.

Comment: List questions are not a good match for SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both javascript and python have API libraries support and documents for them. By far, javascript library is most well developed but also note that it has moved on to typescript:

- [iota.js](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.js)
- [iota.lib.py](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.py)

As for community tutorials, I recommend following to start with:

- [IOTA Developer Essentials](https://iota101.info/)
- [IOTA tutorial videos by Mobilefish](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLmL13yqb6OxdIf6CQMHf7hUcDZBbxHyza)

You can easily learn about sending transactions following the Developer Essentials. And tutorial videos provide further resources and fundamental know-hows.

Comment: very good, the developer essentials seems to be a very good source. why typescript instead of js?

Comment: Not sure, maybe it's a trend. At some point, it still can be used as js library I think.